# Add data validation using an Indirect formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add data validation to a column in my workbook that is based off of an Indirect formula.  I keep getting a 1004 error but not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note that Column Z is also a data validation column so not sure if that has something to do with it?

```
With ws.Range("AA3:AA" & lRow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(Z3)"
    .ShowError = False
End With
```

Comment: Does `Z3` contain a valid value (e.g. some defined name, I presume?) at run-time? AFAIK you can't programmatically add a data validation rule that points to an invalid source *at the time the rule is created*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug yes, I set up Z3's data validation right before I do this step.  But do you mean if there is nothing in Z3 before I set up this validation it won't work?

Comment: Exactly. I have order forms with that exact kind of logic, and the only way I could make it work was by doing everything directly on the worksheet, without any VBA. Which, to be honest, is a much better solution (no macros needed!).

Comment: Perhaps you can just reference the named range inside your Indirect() statement in VBA. Not sure about that though, but worth a try.